# How do I make a HTTPS GET Request that competes against other parties and tries to be the fastest?

Tags: java, node.js, rest, https, low-latency

What can be done in order to outperform "standard" implementations of GET-Requests?

I've used the HttpsURLConnection-Class in java, the request-,req-fast- and the http-module in nodejs, however all of them seem to perform pretty much in the same way.

The rule is: First Come, First Serve! Even the reply is irrelevant.

Is there any specific language to do such thing?

Comment: Any known method to "outperform" other methods will soon be the standard method that everyone uses, causing it to lose its advantage. There may be a way that we don't know, but it's unlikely that someone who knows that way will share it on StackOverflow, for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Your app's performance**
.

> Is there any specific language to do such thing

That's too wide/generic question. I am almost certain, the usual answer you will get is try to go as low level as possible in the language level (go to C if not assembly), or ditch the versatility of microprocessor and go with FPGA or go all the way to ASIC. If you are using higher level language, look at zero copy data structures , pre-rendering as much as possible etc (Not sure how much of this is applicable for a `GET` request though as no `Requestbody` involved). This goes without saying, profile each of the solution and see for yourself which gives you better performance

**2. Network latency**

get your client deployed in the same rack / same data center as that of the server. Key is to get your client as close as possible to the server in terms of network latency.